# Does Liquibase or any plug-ins support data encryption for SQL insert, update statements?

Tags: encryption, liquibase

I'd like to insert, update encrypted data to the database. 
If I need to write code to perform the encryption, how can I integrate the encrypted data with the SQL statements using Liquibase?

Answer (score 1):

Liquibase in general is not used for dealing with the data in a database, but primarily the structure of the tables, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with `sql` tag. You can use it to execute any SQL query you like.

For example:

```
<changeSet id="theId" author="theAuthor">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <columnExists tableName="user" columnName="password"/>
    </preConditions>
    <comment>encrypt passwords</comment>
    <sql>
        UPDATE `user` SET `password` = TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT("password", "key_str"));
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```